# Draw a point with a label in a defined function PGF Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

i would like to plot a function with PGF and also plot some points that belong to a function with a label.
I defined the function and plotted it with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [declare function = {f(\x) = -0.05*\x^3 -0.5*\x^2;}]
\begin{axis}
\addplot [blue, domain=-10:10] {f(x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And i tried to mark the points with labels with `\node`, but i always get errors when i try to do so letting PGF calculate the y-value using the declared function `f(\x)`.
How can i solve my problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Next time, please post a complete example --- a lot depends on your preamble.
Anyway, I think that you are looking for this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [declare function = {f(\x) = -0.05*\x^3 -0.5*\x^2;}]
\begin{axis}
\addplot [blue, domain=-10:10] {f(x)};
\path (-1,{f(-1)}) node[circle, fill=red]{}
    node[below=4pt ]{-1, \pgfmathparse{f(-1)}\pgfmathresult};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In coordinates, you have to hide the `()` to the parser, so you have to protect them in a couple of braces.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem!

Answer (score 4):

You weren't very specific so I present only two solutions to your problem. The advantage over [Rmano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583996/95441) is, that it works for **any** `\addplot` command, i.e. not only for the ones that plot a given function.

For details, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        f(\x) = -0.05*\x^3 - 0.5*\x^2;
    },
]
    \begin{axis}
        % first plot the function
        \addplot+ [
            domain=-10:10,
            % here we only want the line
            no markers,
            % in case the next plot should use the same color
            % (from the `cycle list`)
            forget plot,
        ] {f(x)};

        % second set the marks at the desired positions
        \addplot+ [
            % here we only want the markers ...
            only marks,
            % ... at the positions in this list ...
            samples at={-9,-5},
            % ... together with their corresponding y value
            % (which is the default) ...
            nodes near coords,
        ] {f(x)};

        \addplot+ [
            only marks,
            samples at={-1,3},
            % ... but you can define it your needs, e.g.
            nodes near coords={%
                \footnotesize
                $(\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
                  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})$%
            },
            % but you dan do a lot more stuff.
            % If you are curious, search in the PGFPlots manual for
            % "nodes near coords" or here on TeX.SX for the tag "nodes near coords"
            % (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes-near-coords)
        ] {f(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]